# SQL correspoding ID in new column i another table

Tags: sql

In the  Northwind test base, I created a dictionary table containing all Countries  (a total of 25 countries from 4 different tables), then I assigned ID numbers to these countries.

Now I should replace the Country Columns in these 4 tables, the CountryID column whose id number will correspond to the Countries from the dictionary table. And here is the problem, because I know how to create a column, a relationship, but I don't know how to insert data to ID that will correspond.

Comment: Can you please post some sample data to demonstrate the problem? Not everyone knows Northwind...

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

In a generic way, you would add the `countryId` to a `referencing` table with logic like this:

```
alter table referencing add column countryId int;

update r
    set countryId = c.countryId
    from referencing r join
         countries c
         on r.country = c.country;
```

You might then want to drop the original `country` column:

```
alter table referencing drop column country;
```

You would repeat this process for all four tables.